# this in chained jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

does anyone have an idea if there is a leaner way to write this piece of code?

```js
$('#element').html(
 $('#element').data('test')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element" data-test="test"></div>
```

I'm thinking about using "this" instead of repeating the selector. Due to the scope it doesn't work like that:

```
// doesn't work!
$('#element').html(
    $(this).data('test');
);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Seriously, even with `this` you're unnecessarily instantiating a new jquery object...

Comment: because this is `window` or whatever block scope you are in.... you are not calling it in a function....

Comment: This is an XY Problem. Can you explain what the use-case is for doing this? Is it for *all* divs on a page? Or just *one* specific div? You'll get a better solution if we know your actual end-goal.

Comment: @TylerRoper tried to make this example as easy as it can be.

Comment: @FelixGeenen I understand, but you've made it *too* simple. Without knowing what you're actually trying to do, we can't give you a good answer. I'm not saying to include your whole page or anything, just one or two lines of context about what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: of course I know that I can use a variable.. just wondering if there are leaner ways...

Comment: @FelixGeenen perhaps but you haven't really provided a use case. Tyler is right, you oversimplified it

Comment: If you are asking for a "leaner" way, this question is off topic, as it is asking about refactoring.  You need to state a problem, why the code does not work, and what you expect "working" to mean.

Comment: @charlietfl updated it :)

Comment: Well @Taplar has given you the answer below. Your `this` context is the issue. it is the same `this` as doing `console.log(this); $('#element').html(   $(this).data('test')); `

Comment: thanks for explaining but as i already wrote in the question i'm aware what the problem is. I'm searching for a nice solution if there is one

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as Taplar has written a perfectly good answer, but you insist  you're searching for "a nice solution if there is one". I don't think anyone knows what you're actually asking for at this point; it's both unclear and too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give it a callback function that will have the `this` scoped.

```js
$('div').html(function(){
  return $(this).data('test');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-test="test"></div>
<div data-test="secondary test"></div>
```

Or, seriously, just use a variable (if there is only one).

```js
var $div = $('#element');

$div.html($div.data('test'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element" data-test="test"></div>
```

Comment: Those approaches would produce different results with multiple `<div>`

Comment: @FelixGeenen Taplar's second example in the answer above is likely the one you'd want to use if you're targeting an element by its ID.

Comment: And the first example would loop over multiple elements in a collection and return the instance specific value.